# Permission denied, running C++ program bash

Tags: c++, bash

I have written and compiled a c program, however I am unable to run it using bash.

I compiled it using the following:
    `g++ -g -Wall -o hello hello.cpp`

then tried to run it with:
    `./hello`

which gave me:

```
bash: ./hello: Permission denied
```

Comment: I've tried that, it gives:     sudo: ./hello: command not found

Comment: I strongly suspect the `noexec` attribute is set.

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that the filesystem you're working on is not mounted with the `noexec` option (which forbids any program to be executed on that filesystem, irrelevant of its executable flag).

An easy way to verify it is to use the `mount` command and see which mount point corresponds to the directory where you're compiling. If that mount point contains the `noexec` option, edit your `/etc/fstab` accordingly and either remount the filesystem or just reboot your system.